# ODI 12c: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: oracle, clob, oracle-data-integrator

I have a .csv file in which the lenght of a field is more or less 8000 bytes. Using ODI Studio I mapped this field as a string of 15000 bytes in the Model section. In the db oracle I am trying to store data with CLOB datatypes. But, I am getting this error: "can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column".

How can I store this column?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to_lob oracle function, apply to_lob(modelname.columnname) in mapping tab.

Make sure that data which flows from source has only LONG acceptable values, and can be parsed to a CLOB value. Otherwise it will throw an error.

If that error throws off, then try to treat it with case when statements and then apply to_lob.